# Bootstrap 3 Tooltips not triggering as intended

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, tooltip, twitter-bootstrap-3, twitter-bootstrap-tooltip

I found a lot of questions about Bootstrap 3 Tooltips but no one of them is resolving my issue.

Here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/qa22N/

`$('#mytooltip').tooltip()`

The code above is not working, see the Fiddle example.

What am I doing wrong? I don't know why the tooltip is not showing at all. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is working, it is just showing above the link, and so is appearing off screen. Adding `data-placement="auto"` causes the tooltip to move to a position where it would be on screen, solving the problem.

Working fork of your code: http://jsfiddle.net/designingsean/qa22N/1/

Comment: Thanks Sean, last question, it's better to use "data-original-title" or "title"?

Comment: Well, using `title` will give you a fallback if the javascript fails to load for whatever reason. It should give you the browser's built-in hover, a la alt tags on images. So if you want the info in the tooltip to always be accessible, then I would go with `title`. If not then go with `data-title`.

Comment: Also, note that both `data-title` and `data-original-title` work. I have no idea why they included both.